# Redis Stream with Node XADD

Tags: node.js, redis, node-modules, node-redis

How can one use Redis stream in redis-node.

Redis documentation for XADD is:

```
XADD mystream * key1 "Value1" key2 "Value2"
```

This will add a single entry with the given key value pairs. * specifies that the id should be automatically generated.

I tried to execute it in Node:

```
redisClient.xadd("myStream", "*", "name", "anant");
```

but I just got an error saying XADD is not defined.

Comment: `redis-node` also uses camel casing for command names: `redisClient.xAdd()`

Answer (score 5):

You may be using an old version of the Redis client, or an old version of Redis server. Streams were added in Redis 5.0, which was only released less than a year ago, in late 2018.